# wrong text encoding on linux

Tags: c++, linux, encoding

I downloaded a source code `.rar` file from internet to my linux server. Then, I extract all source files into local directory. When I use "cat" command to see the content of each file, the wrong text encoding is shown on my terminal (There are some chinese characters in the source file).

I use

```
file -bi testapi.cpp
```

then shows:

```
text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I tried to convert that file to uft-8 encoding with following command:

```
iconv -f ISO88591 -t UTF8 testapi.cpp > new.cpp
```

But it doesn't work.

I set my `.vimrc` file with following two lines:

```
set encoding=utf-8

set fileencoding=utf-8
```

After this, when I `vim testapi.cpp`, the chinese characters will be normally displayed in the vim. But `cat testapi.cpp` doesn't work.

When I compile and run the program, the `printf` statement with chinese characters will print wrong characters like `????`

What should I do to display correct chinese characters when I run the program?

Comment: I tried `iconv -f latin1 -t UTF8 testapi.cpp`, it just change to another way of wrong characters. I also tried `iconv -f latin1 -t GB2312 testapi.cpp`, it complains about "iconv: illegal input sequence at position 551". The position 551 is exactly where the chinese character first appears in the file. Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to convert from the files original charset (I doubt its `latin1`) to `UTF8`.

Comment: Does the document contain Chinese characters? Then it’s definitely not [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)! You have to find a better match for the source encoding. I’d try Vim. You can switch encoding on the fly, no need for editing `.vimrc` each time. Just type, for example `:set encoding=utf-8` and press Enter.

Comment: Hi, yes! 
I opened the file on my mac, then type `:set fileencoding` + `Enter` in the vim, it shows the "fileencodng=latin1". So that's why I tried above iconv command.
This time, I reopen the file on the linux server with vim and then type `:set fileencoding` + `Enter`, it shows that "fileenoding=cp936". Then I use the command `iconv -f cp936 -t utf-8 testapi.cpp`, it works!
The Chinese characters correctly displayed on the screen! Thank you very much!

Comment: "But cat testapi.cpp doesn't work." There's many things that can go wrong here. a) Your terminal isn't set to UTF-8. Check what the LANG environment variable is. b) your terminal emulator (perhaps you're using putty ?) isn't set to UTF-8 ? c) The font of your terminal emulator doesn't have the required glyphs for the characters you're trying to view.

Comment: Hi nos, yes, but it's not the terminal's problem. After I run `iconv -f cp936 -t utf-8 testapp.cpp > new.cpp`, then `cat new.cpp` works well.

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR Quickest Solution: Copy/Paste the Visible Text to a Brand-New, Confirmed UTF-8 File

Your file is *marked* as latin1, but the data is *stored* as utf8.

When you set `set-enc=utf8` or `set fileencoding=utf-8` in VIM, you're not changing the data or converting it.  You're looking at the same exact data, but interpreting as if it is the utf8 charset.  So, good news: *Your data is good.*  No conversion or changing necessary.

You just need to put *the same exact data* into a file already *marked as UTF-8* encoding.  That can be done easily by simply making a brand new file in vim, using `set enc=utf8`, and then copy-pasting your old data into the new file.  You can test this out by making a testfile with the only text *"汉语"* ("chinese language"), set enc, save, close, reopen, and see that the text didn't get corrupted.  And you can test with `file -bi $pathtofile`, though that is not super reliable.

Anyway, TLDR: Make a brand new UTF-8 file, confirm that it's utf-8, make your data visible, and then copy/paste and/or transfer it to the new UTF-8 file, *without* doing any conversion.

Also, theoretically, I considered that `iconv -f utf8 -t utf8` would work, since all I wanted to do was make utf-8-encoded data be marked as utf-8-encoded, *without changing it.*  But this gave me an error that indicated it was still trying to do a data conversion.